# jQuery: slide header when user scrolls past a point

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
if($(window).scrollTop()>=220) {
                    $('#header nav').slideUp('fast').removeClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    $('#header nav').addClass('fixed').slideDown('fast');
                }
```

What happens is that when a user scrolls further than 220 pixels down the page the header will get class of fixed and then slide down. When the user moves back up again then the header will slide up and have its class of fixed removed. The user will never see the header move back into its original position as its done around 180 pixels so is off screen.

The problem however is that it will do the slide over and over again when ever the user scrolls which isn't quite what I want. I've looked at the stop method but stopping the current animation is also not what I need.. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The code above is a function called like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                    fixedHeader();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `if($(window).scrollTop()>=220) {` line to be checking whether the user has transitioned from 0-220 to 220+ or reverse, rather than every the scroll wheel is used.

An example tutorial with lots of comments can be [found here.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1810-Creating-A-Sometimes-Fixed-Position-Element-With-jQuery.htm)

Comment: Could you share an example. I've fiddled with this a fair bit and it either breaks it or does the same.

Comment: There's an [example here with lots of commenting](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1810-Creating-A-Sometimes-Fixed-Position-Element-With-jQuery.htm), that I hope clears it up a bit. Around the 33rd line of JavaScript is where the applicable logic happens

Answer (score 0):

Doing this fixes the issue:

```
if(!$('#header nav').hasClass('fixed')) {
                        $('#header nav').addClass('fixed').slideDown('fast');
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This resource might help you: [*Scroll Activated slide Down*](http://return-true.com/2010/04/scroll-activated-slide-down-header-with-jquery/)

```
$(function() {
    var bar = $('#headerSlideContainer');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : '0px'}, 500);
        } else {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this, it worked for me.

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {

var div = $('#header');
var start = $(div).offset().top;

$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    var p = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
    $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
});

});
</SCRIPT>
```

Taken from 
[Fixed Header](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2012/01/scroll-fix-header-jquery-facebook.html)

Comment: **I already have that functionality working!** My issue is making it slideDown without continuing to slideDown everytime the user scrolls.

Comment: Then you didn't post all your code. Try this jsfiddle with the code I'm telling you about [link](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/J5rKX/1/). This is with your code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/J5rKX/). As you can see the first example wont continue to slide while your example code wont even slide.